# Why is arcpy overwriting datetime in __main__? How do I fix it without rearranging my imports?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.3

Consider the following scripts:

`import_test1.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
import import_test2
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
from datetime import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
```

`import_test2.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
import arcpy
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
from datetime import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
```

Now run this script:

```
C:\temp>py -2 .\import_test1.py
__main__: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
import_test2: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
import_test2: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
import_test2: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
__main__: <module 'datetime' (built-in)>
__main__: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

This is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (I encountered the issue in a more complex script, but this suffices to reproduce the behavior.)

As you can see, importing `arcpy` (*not* doing a `from arcpy import *`, just a plain `import arcpy`) is overwriting my module's import when it's the `__main__` script. It replaces the type I imported with the module of the same name, which is not what I need.

I know it's arcpy because I can reproduce it with an even simpler script:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
import arcpy
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
from datetime import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
```

Gives:

```
C:\temp>py -2 .\import_test.py
__main__: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
__main__: <module 'datetime' (built-in)>
__main__: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I don't want to reorder my modules because I want to follow [PEP8's guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) on order of imports: standard library, third party, local application/library specific imports. This is also hard to manage if some other module performs the import of `arcpy`, as in my two-module example.

How can I get `arcpy` to stop overwriting variables that don't belong to it? Why is it even doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The arcpy developers may be distributing a modified version of datetime with arcpy, one with bug fixes, and may be monkeypatching the `__main__` namespace on import of arcpy. Here's an example of how it works.

The module mypy, below, imports the os module (with the name `os`) and then reassigns `__main__.datetime` to the value of `os` (the os module).

```
# mypy.py:

import __main__
import os

__main__.datetime = os
```

If we import mypy after importing datetime, it "fixes" our code.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> repr(datetime)
"<type 'datetime.datetime'>"
>>> import mypy
>>> repr(datetime)
"<module 'os' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>"
```

It's not wrong to do this. Sometimes you really need to patch upstream code. The problem with Python's datetime module is that the module and class name are the same and there are different usage idioms: `import datetime; datetime.datetime()` vs `from datetime import datetime; datetime()`. It seems like arcpy patches the first and breaks the second.

Switching to `import datetime` and calling `datetime.datetime()` in all your code that uses arcpy should be a good solution.

Comment: No, it's using the built-in module. (Can't even get a file path off it.) `import datetime` will still pick up on the same module that `arcpy` inserts. So even if ESRI is using a customized `datetime`, that customization wouldn't be a reason for `arcpy` to modify `__main__`'s (or any other module's) runtime variables as part of its own import process. Relying on such runtime monkey-patching would also be ill-advised, as they'd have to do it to *every single module* that imports `arpcy` (which it clearly doesn't do).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to work around it is to alias the type under another name:

```
# We have to alias the class because arcpy overwrites datetime in __main__
from datetime import datetime as DateTime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, DateTime))
import arcpy
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, DateTime))
```

The other alternative is to roll with `arcpy`'s modification of your module's variables:

```
# We have to use datetime directly because arcpy overwrites datetime in __main__
import datetime
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
import arcpy
print(u'{}: {}'.format(__name__, datetime))
```

I have no idea why `arcpy` behaves this way.